# "back substitution" method for solving linear system

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm using numpy to write the "back substitution" method for solving linear system where "A" is a nonsingular upper triangular matrix.

```
import numpy as np

def upperTriSol(A, b):
    n = np.size(b)
    x = np.zeros_like(b)

    x[-1] = 1. / A[-1, -1] * b[-1]
    for i in xrange(n-2, -1, -1):
        x[i] = 1. / A[i, i] * (b[i] - np.sum(A[i, i+1:] * x[i+1:]))

    return x
```

I know that "for loops" are slow, so I wonder if there is any way to avoid them in this case? If not, is there a "correct" way to write efficient "for loops" in numpy?

Comment: What was wrong with [`numpy.linalg.solve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html)?

Comment: @GarethRees Nothing wrong with it. It's just some college stuff we need to write by ourselves. It works already, just want to improve a little if possible.

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain that, please?

Answer (score 1):

A few quick suggestions that I may flesh out in further edits:

If looks like `x[i]` is a function of `x[i+1]` and selected items from `A` and `b`.  Then it could also be seen as forward itertion on a reversed list, `xr[i+1]` dependent on `xr[i]`.

`np.cumsum` and related accumulated functions are often useful in problems like this.

There's a set of `tri` functions that give you indices and values on upper and lower triangular matrices.

Typically 'vectorizing' in `numpy` requires stepping back a bit from the problem and imagining in terms of operations on a table or 2d array of values.

(this question would have gotten more attention on SO).